# Given an non-null integer matrix, calculate the sum of it's elements

Tags: python-3.x

Input: First line contains T, which is the number of test cases. First line of each test case contains two integers N, M and N lines follow which contains M spaced integers.

Input:

1

2 3

1 0 0

8 -9 -1

Output:

-1

The code I've written is:

```
a = int(input())

for _ in range(a):

    b = list(map(int,input().split()))

    c = [[int(j) for j in input().split()] for i in range(len(b))]

    print(sum(sum(x) if isinstance(x,list) else x for x in c))
```

I get the output correct. But, I'm unable to submit it because of some arising errors.

Comment: What errors arise? Where do you want to submit the code?

Comment: I'm solving the problem in GeeksforGeeks platform. When I submit the code, I get EOFError: EOF when reading a line.

Comment: Does that site use Python 2? If yes, you should change `input` to `raw_input`.